# Can i switch negative feedback to positive feedback in PID control?

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control

I am learning Control Theory and i have a confusion about whether the following PID controllers are interchangeable or similar.

1. Are they equivalent? Why?
2. Is there any difference in how i would implement both of them in code? I have to program this in Arduino.

Here is the first control loop which is the normal definition of a PID controller:

[image: pid1]

And here is the changed one with the negative feedback changed to positive and the setpoint changed from positive to negative.

[image: pid2]

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call this positive feedback. Most definitions of positive feedback generally assume that the setpoint and measurement/feedback are added in phase (typically both with a plus sign).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change that willy-nilly.

The second diagram is perfectly valid, however, *if* the plant tends to operate in reverse from normal.  If you have a plant whose output gets more negative when its input goes positive then you'd use the second one.

Comment: They can of course be made equivalent if you are allowed to specify negative gains. I have not (yet) seen that implemented in practice...